# client rendering react component to html in browser client side with styles

Tags: reactjs

I have a development requirement, I need to render the React component in the client browser, generate it to html string and send it to the backend's puppeteer headless browser, puppeteer convert the html to a pdf file and send it back to the front end for printing or other purpose. So I must distill or collect the styles and send it with the html string. For some reason, all the render work must be down in client side.

I noticed styled-components have an api have server render ability . And it also have some trick to do it in client.

```
const {StyleSheet} = require('styled-components').__DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_HAUNTED_BY_SPOOKY_GHOSTS
StyleSheet.reset(true)
```

But it also have a warning it is not encouraged to use it in frontend, and may cause some ghost problem.

I need a solution to render react component to html with styles in browser client side.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `renderToString` from `react-dom/server`. It will render component to string. Also you may pass styles as `style` prop for any html element, so styles also will be outputted to string together with html tags.

For example having component

```
function SomeComponent () {
  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>Some component with custom styles</div>
}
```

We can do

```
let stringRepresentation = renderToString(<SomeComponent/>);
```

`stringRepresentation` will contain html code as browser get it. So you can send this string to backend.

Full example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56845530-cbfyy)

Comment: what if I use some UI or css library in my code , I can't force the people who use my code only use the inline-styles. What about external css, and If I use the styled-components?